# Where is this picture taken?

Tags: visual

Your only clue is this picture. You have to find where it has been taken!

[image]

I will add some hints if noone finds.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, unless someone actually happens to visit this particular station often. The only thing to go off in this picture is the possible logo on the train. Even if it is a logo and you find the train company it belongs to, you then have all that countries rail stations to go through, every single platform, to find this exact location. I don't think anyone want's to do that, or possibly even could do that.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, if you think you can not find the station, you can provide an intermediate answer with the country or the state that'd have my +1, and potentially help others :)

Comment: @JKHA true, but I have no idea how anyone could even get that far

Comment: I like these. These are possible.

Comment: I've downvoted because there doesn't seem to be an intended "path to the answer" -- the only real way to solve it seems to be already being familiar with that location.

Comment: Is this a steganography puzzle? If so, please put in the [steganography] or [enigmatic-puzzle] tags. My random guess here is the Todaimae Station [N12] in Tokyo on the Namboku line.

Comment: In the gist of "you're in a hot-air balloon" from [this joke](https://unijokes.com/joke-6757/): The picture has been taken on a railway platform. :)

Comment: In a train station?

Comment: @Deusovi, it seems that the selected answer prooves you wrong. I think both answer's writers never went to this station.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Based on the find by @plasticinsect,

> I've looked at the 18 stations on the [Line 9 (Emerald line)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_9_(CPTM)) and I think I've found a match! Of the 18 stations, only 2 (as far as I could tell) had stairs leading **down** from the platform, while the rest had stairs leading **up**. The 2 stations were    Autódromo and Primavera-Interlagos, but only Autódromo seems to fit all the clues in the picture.

Here's a zoom from Google Earth:

> [image]

The picture in the OP appears to have been taken

> by the red fire extinguisher, facing mainly towards the stairs.

The matching clues are:

> The emerald station sign
>  The fire extinguisher on the pole to the right
>  The camera hanging from the ceiling
>  The black information board (I assume) over the stairs
>  The general layout of the roof and the poles holding it up

Comment: Impressive search :)

Comment: @JKHA Thanks! Took just a couple of hours.

Answer (score 17):

Partial answer:

> This is one of the 94 [CPTM transit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companhia_Paulista_de_Trens_Metropolitanos) stations that exist in the state of São Paulo, Brazil. I have no way of knowing which station it is, however.
>  I found this by creating a cropped, rotated, and stretched version of the logo from the image:
>  [image]
>  and then doing a reverse image search on this logo. The "Pages that include matching images" section of the results gave me the name of the transit agency, and then it was a simple matter to search Wikipedia for that.

Comment: You could probably narrow it down to Line 9 or 10 given the color of the station sign.

Comment: This is a BIG improvement for the answer, and if I could have selected a second one for the answer, it'd clearly be you :)

Comment: @JKHA No worries. I definitely think Jens has earned the check mark here. I posted this partial answer so it could be used as a starting point by others to find the full answer. If I hadn't wanted anyone to do that, I wouldn't have posted.